# Retrieve Wordpress post with featured image/thumbnail in one sql query

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

here's my code :

```
SELECT p.ID, p.post_title,
MAX(IF(pm.meta_key = 'featured_image', pm.meta_value, NULL)) AS event_imgID
FROM wpgp_posts AS p
LEFT JOIN wpgp_postmeta AS pm on pm.post_id = p.ID
WHERE p.post_type = 'product' and p.post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY p.ID
```

event_imgID retrieve the ID from postmeta but the img url is stored in the wpgp_posts in the guid column

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the way to do it. I had to search thumbnail_id  instead of guid :

```
SELECT
        p1.ID, p1.post_title,
         MAX(IF(pm.meta_key = 'listing_event_date', pm.meta_value, NULL)) AS event_date,
        wm2.meta_value as event_img
    FROM 
        wpgp_posts p1
        LEFT JOIN wpgp_postmeta AS pm on (pm.post_id = p1.ID)
    LEFT JOIN 
        wpgp_postmeta wm1
        ON (
            wm1.post_id = p1.id 
            AND wm1.meta_value IS NOT NULL
            AND wm1.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'              
        )
    LEFT JOIN 
        wpgp_postmeta wm2
        ON (
            wm1.meta_value = wm2.post_id
            AND wm2.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
            AND wm2.meta_value IS NOT NULL  
        )
    WHERE
        p1.post_status='publish' 
        AND p1.post_type='product'
        GROUP BY p1.ID, wm2.meta_id
    ORDER BY 
        event_date ASC
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can join in the table to get more information about the image:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM (SELECT p.ID, p.post_title,
             MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'featured_image' THEN pm.meta_value END) AS event_imgID
      FROM wpgp_posts p LEFT JOIN
           wpgp_postmeta pm 
           ON pm.post_id = p.ID
      WHERE p.post_type = 'product' and p.post_status = 'publish'
      GROUP BY p.ID
     ) pi LEFT JOIN
     wpgp_posts wp
     ON pi.event_imgID = wp.guid
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I make error, it's wpgp_posts with "s". I try your code but it don't seems to work I use your code and make SELECT * [your code] all value is NULL

Comment: event_imgID is the ID of the img post. The image post contain the url of the image in guid column.